# Navigation drawer open after popping fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

So I have an activity with a fragment in it, the fragment has a navigation drawer and the page's content. When I open the drawer and click an item the fragment is replaced with a new fragment. When I press the back button I call popBackStack on the fragment manager and it goes back to the first fragment but the navigation drawer is open.

A couple things to note: When pressing an item in the drawer I call closeDrawers on the drawer layout and the drawer closes while the fragment is replaced. If I press the UP button in the action bar I can replace the fragment container with a NEW main fragment, but I'd prefer to be able to pop the fragment off the stack.

Why is the drawer sticking open when I return to the main fragment?

In the click listener for drawer items:

```
case 4:
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        Fragment aboutFragment = new AboutFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, aboutFragment, "AboutFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
```

This is the UP arrow in the action bar, this works but is hacky:

```
case android.R.id.home:
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainActivityFragment())
            .commit();
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

with

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer();
```

Comment: Yeah! It's work when I implemented Navigation Host Fragment and get back from that. So, solved my problem. `drawerLayout.closeDrawers();` closes the drawer but after coming back from fragment its opening the drawer again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreateView of your firt fragment, just close the drawer
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

Comment: I've tried that unfortunately. It still shows that it's open

Comment: Did you put it as the last statement of your navigational drawer?

Comment: Or one more thing you can do is close the navigational drawer after you pop() in the back button code